# Social Share count api for Twiiter, GooglePlus (2017)

Tags: socialshare

I need to get social share count for main media including Twitter and GooglePlus. However, things changed as what've known so far

- For Twitter, I couldn't use cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://{URL}
- For GooglePlus share.yandex.net/counter/gpp/?callback=@&url={URL}

I made some search but couldn't find a good way. Previously, I use donreach.com https://donreach.com/docs/social-api/getting-started/ but for some reasons, it's server unreachable. I tried to find alternative solution like ShareThis (not working properly) but until now, I can't find one.

Comment: Same issue to me, I used http://js-socials.com/demos/ but now, Share Count on Twitter and G+ disappeared